# After restarting weblogic scheduled jobs are not triggering

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

After restart of weblogic server ,jobs which were scheduled are not triggering scheduled jobs. Below is the code.
            1.I am using CronTrigger
            2.I am using jobdetail

```
    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    trigger.setName(userId+"_"+packetId+"_"+jobFolderName);
    trigger.setGroup(userId);
    trigger.setCronExpression(cronexpression);
    trigger.setStartTime(starttimedate);
    trigger.setEndTime(endtimedate);

trigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_SMART_POLICY);
                          

    job.setName(userId+"_"+packetId+"_"+jobFolderName);
    job.setGroup(userId);
    job.setVolatility(true);
    //job.setRequestsRecovery(true);
    job.setDurability(true);

Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
                                 
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    trigger.setStartTime(starttimedate);
    trigger.setEndTime(endtimedate);
                                      
trigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_SMART_POLICY);
                                        
    job.setName(userId+"_"+packetId+"_"+jobFolderName);            
    job.setGroup(userId);
    job.setVolatility(true);
    job.setRequestsRecovery(true);
    job.setDurability(true);

    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    Scheduler.start();
    Scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

I am using quartz 1.6.3 version.

Comment: can you check the log and add code to log each details ?

Comment: There is no traces for this in log i checked .In eclipse console no traces of  jobs.i am checking on local web logic server

Comment: Please post your Quartz properties file. Are you using JDBCJobStore? If yes, you can check the QRTZ tables to see when the job would be triggered next and whether that changes after the restart of your server. If you use RAMJobStore then what you have is the expected behavior.

Comment: I have not created any quartz properties file.I am not using jdbcjobstore,also i am not using RAMjobstore.Please guide me how to use RAMJobstore

Comment: @PradeepL you should use JDBCJobStore, because RAMJobstore saves all data in the RAM, so when your server stops, all your data is deleted. You **are** currently using a JobStore, the question is which one. Please read this http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html (and this is for quartz 1.X http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson09)